Is <ng-container> a structural directive?
I don't think so. I was asked this in an interview and I answered saying that  does what the name suggests, it acts as a container and nothing more.
According to the official documentation on Angular website - Documentation
The  allows us to use structural directives without any extra element, making sure that the only DOM changes being applied are those dictated by the directives themselves.
It isn't a structural directive in angular right?

Hm that's a trick question :D Angular docs speak of ng-container as "special element", but also as an "element that hosts directives, "grouping element". For Angular v2 docs it explicitely says that ng-container is a "syntax element recognized by the Angular parser. It's not a directive, component, class, or interface". Go figure xD

It's hard to describe what it is, but definitely it's not a structural directive.

it is a special "if" condition in angular compiler.

sure, thanks for the answer you guys. After much research I have concluded it is not a structural directive.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You're absolutely right!
ng-container is not a structural directive. It's just a logical wrapper that doesn't add any elements to the DOM.
While structural directives like *ngIf and *ngFor modify the DOM, ng-container helps apply them without cluttering the HTML with extra tags.
